# How to invoke a call to a URL from an Andorid app?

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, azure

Disclaimer. I'm asking this on someone else's behalf and given that I know as much about Android development as penguins about flight, it may be clumsy. In such case, let me know and I'll remove it or try to reformulate.

---

I've created a web service that's reachable at the URL on the following form.

> http://server/Blopp.svc/Store/value1/value2

The back-end part I've got covered but I'm worried about the front-end development. I've got a colleague that's making the app and he's got the rudimentary GUI done. However, in order not to do a lot of convoluted coding, he's heard that there's a certain library for making such URL calls.

What's the name of it? Is there certain other aspects to take into consideration or is there an (almost) standard one that everybody uses?

Please not that the app's functionality is at the moment limited to providing the web service with data. All the logic and presentation is done on the website and not inside the app.

I've never built up an Android app, so I'm asking for understanding if this is a dumb formulation. I just want to help my co-worker and he seemed to struggle with the details.

Is there perhaps a smoother way to make the call to a web service if I substitute the patter of the URL to use query strings? Any other approach that makes it easier for an Android developer? I'm not familiar with the area but I want to make things easy for my team-mate.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. "Is there certain other aspects to take into consideration or is there an (almost) standard one that everybody uses?" -- beyond the off-topic issue, it will be difficult for anyone to help you, because you have not explained anything about the Web service. You cite a URL, and you seem to think that it is somehow special, but *all* Web services have URLs. There are countless HTTP clients for Android, both built in (e.g., `HttpUrlConnection`) and through libraries. What is your specific concern?

Comment: @CommonsWare According to him, there's no built-in easy way to make that call. And I was hoping for a de facto standard approach that I'm used to on the .NET side. It was mentioned that not using the query strings made it more difficult for him, hence the example URL. My apologies if the question is diffuse. I'm asking it on someone else's account, so to say. Please see the update at the top of the question.

Comment: Using `HttpURLConnection` is about as straightforward as it gets, and is not complicated at all, unless you are a complete beginner programmer. What exactly is the hang up? This class is even recommended in the [Google docs on making web calls](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html). It's all pretty straightforward, so I'm not really sure where the confusion is stemming from.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe As I'm asking on someone else's behalf, I can only speculate. Since I have no reason to believe other than good things about my colleague and I trust that he's skilled developer, it could be a simple case of mental constipation - one has a load of substance but nothing comes out. It's like that sometime for me. Even with the most basic stuff. He's got that working now and the app is up for download. Too bad I can't talk about it (sneaking in self-promo is purely pathetic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different HTTP libraries available and it would really depend on your specific requirements which one you used (if any - you can roll your own HTTP requests using HttpURLConnection)  Two of the more popular ones are:

**Volley**

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Written by one of the guys on the Google Play team and part of the AOSP.  Very flexible and easy to use however I would hesitate to recommend it as it relies on the now deprecated Apache Http classes in its public API.

**Retrofit**

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

From Square.  Version 2 is currently in late stages of beta.  It allows you to define your API as an interface.  It has dependancies on their OkHttp library as well.  Very fast and also has RxJava support baked in.

Comment: He went with something called OkHttp. Apparently there are a lot of frameworks to pick from. I'd feel less confused if there were only or two emerging as de facto industry standard. Having said that, I won't be creating that app, just the back-bone, so I won't have to get unconfused, hehe.